# looping over multi dimensional array with php to init another array

Tags: php, arrays

i want to initialize an associative array where the key is a date and the value is Boolean , 1 for attended in class and 0 for not. for some reason there is one date initialized with 1 instead of 0 and i cant figure out why.

this is the loop:

```
foreach ($students_list as $key => $student) {
    $student_id = $student['student'];
    $student_presence_arr = $presence_arr[$student_id]; //array of registration dates for each student
    $student_name = $student["first_name"]." ".$student["last_name"];

    foreach ($student_presence_arr as $key=> $attended) { //loop over each date student attended and set to 1 = attended
    $date = strtok($attended['date'], " ");
    $date_arr[$date] = 1;
    }

$table .= '<tr><td>'.$student_name.'</td>';
foreach ($date_arr as $date => $status) {
    if($date < date("Y-m-d")){
    $status == 1 ? $table .= '<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>' : $table .= '<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>';
    }
    else{
    $table .= "<td></td>";
}
}
$table .= '</tr>';

}
```

there are two student currently in the DB.
the `var_dump` of `presence_arr` for student with id  = 5 is this:

```
{ [5]=> array(5) { 
    [0]=> array(4) { ["student"]=> string(1) "5" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-02-14 00:00:00" }
    [1]=> array(4) { ["student"]=> string(1) "5" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-02-28 00:00:00" }
  [2]=> array(4) { ["student"]=> string(1) "5" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-03-27 00:00:00"} 
    [3]=> array(4) { ["student"]=> string(1) "5" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-01-03 05:00:00" } 
    [4]=> array(4) { ["student"]=> string(1) "5" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-01-10 09:00:00"  } 
}
```

and for student with id = 1 is this:

```
 [1]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> array(4) { ["student"]=> string(1) "1" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-01-17 00:00:00" 
 } }
```

but as you can see in the picture..

[image]
for some reason the date 01-17 marked with ✓ for both students though in case of student with id = 5 it should be **X**. any idea what am i missing here?  thx

UPDATE:

`print_r($date_arr)` :

```
Array ( [2016-01-03] => 0 [2016-01-10] => 0 [2016-01-17] => 1 [2016-01-24] => 0 [2016-01-31] => 0 [2016-02-07] => 0 [2016-02-14] => 0 [2016-02-21] => 0 [2016-02-28] => 0 [2016-03-06] => 0 [2016-03-13] => 0 [2016-03-20] => 0 [2016-03-27] => 0 [2016-04-03] => 0 [2016-04-10] => 0 ) Array ( [2016-01-03] => 1 [2016-01-10] => 1 [2016-01-17] => 1 [2016-01-24] => 0 [2016-01-31] => 0 [2016-02-07] => 0 [2016-02-14] => 1 [2016-02-21] => 0 [2016-02-28] => 1 [2016-03-06] => 0 [2016-03-13] => 0 [2016-03-20] => 0 [2016-03-27] => 1 [2016-04-03] => 0 [2016-04-10] => 0 )
```

Comment: Can you `print_r($date_arr)` after you have populated it.

Comment: If you show an example of the `$students_list` AND example of the result you want it is much easier.

Comment: sure.answer updated...as you can see the problematic date stores the value 1 for both of them, but i cant figure out why it stores this date for the id 5 student

Comment: `$students_list` : `Array ( [0] => Array ( [student] => 1 [first_name] => ofek [last_name] => ads ) [1] => Array ( [student] => 5 [first_name] => Al [last_name] => Sade ) ) `...antoher way to pust why i want its to understand why `$date_arr[2016-01-17] => 1` for user with  id 5

Comment: Another question : Why do you use an associative array ? Why not just a list holding oredered dates ? If date is in the list, student attended, if date is not, student was not there... That would reduce complexity a bit.